# C SDL Keyboard Events SDL_KEYUP Triggering When Key Is Down

Tags: c, events, keyboard, sdl, keyup

I am using SDL in C, and I'm trying to make a character move on the screen when a key is pressed, and stop when it is released, but it seems as if the KEYUP event is triggering when the key is still being held down. If I remove the KEYUP section in pressed(), the characters will slide across the screen, but obviously won't stop on their own. If I leave the KEYUP section in, I have to press the key repeatedly to move them across the screen.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's what I have:

```
...

int done = 0;
while (done==0)
{
    pressed();
    if (kenter == 1)
    {
        state = 1;
        subscreen();
    }
    if (kescape == 1)
    {
        done = 1;
    }
    if (kup == 1)
    {
        playery += -2;
    }
    if (kdown == 1)
    {
        playery += 2;
    }

    if (kright == 1)
    {
        playerx += 2;
    }
    if (kleft == 1)
    {
        playerx += - 2;
    }

...

int pressed ()
{

SDL_Event keyevent;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&keyevent))
{
    switch(keyevent.type)
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch(keyevent.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_RETURN:
            {
                kenter = 1;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            {
                kescape = 1;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_a:
            {
                ka = 1;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_s:
            {
                ks = 1;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_UP:
            {
                kup = 1;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_DOWN:
            {
                kdown = 1;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            {
                kright = 1;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_LEFT:
            {
                kleft = 1;
                break;
            }
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    switch(keyevent.type)
    {
        case SDL_KEYUP:
        switch(keyevent.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_RETURN:
            {
                kenter = 0;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            {
                kescape = 0;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_a:
            {
                ka = 0;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_s:
            {
                ks = 0;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_UP:
            {
                kup = 0;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_DOWN:
            {
                kdown = 0;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            {
                kright = 0;
                break;
            }
            case SDLK_LEFT:
            {
                kleft = 0;
                break;
            }
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The extra braces in the switch statement are unusual, and make it harder for me to read the code.

Answer (score 3):

I think your switch statements are broken.

Use this less confusing way

```
int pressed ()
{

    SDL_Event event;

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
    {
        if(event.type == SDLK_KEYDOWN)
        {
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_RETURN:
                        doStuff = 1
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }
        if(event.type == SDLK_KEYUP)
        {
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_RETURN:
                        doStuff = 0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }
    }   
}
```

Also important:

[SDL Tutorials: Practical Keyboard Input](https://web.archive.org/web/20151217024611/http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Practical_Keyboard_Input)

Oh and avoid using global variables!

Comment: Thanks! I switched my switch statement to look like you showed me, but I am still experiencing the same issue. I can't seem to figure out why the variables keep getting set to zero even when no key is being released.

Are global variables bad? Is there another way to get that many variables from a function to another?

Comment: If you want you can show me you whole project and i'll try to find mistakes. Im currently working with SDL and im kinda into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of two `switch` statements is odd and confusing, you should probably fix that.

The issues you're seeing are likely due to keyboard repeat, see the [`SDL_EnableKeyRepeat()`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlenablekeyrepeat.html) call for how to disable it.

Comment: Oops, I'm not sure why I put that there...

Is keyboard repeat is active by default? I haven't touched keyboard repeat at all. I tried to disable it just now by setting the delay parameter to 0 which according to the documentation will disable it, but I am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: In SDL 2+ there is no `SDL_EnableKeyRepeat()`, but `event.key.repeat` will be non-zero on key down events that are the result of repeating and you can just ignore them.

Answer (score -1):

don't use switch. I experienced same thing, but I resolved into using 'if' like this. Maybe switch has 'else if'.

```
if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
....
}
if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP){
....
}
```